# I am a middle school girl with an untrained D3 to D6 range. Is it impressive, and how much could I extend it by with training, aging, etc?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I've never had proper vocal lessons before, and my friend says 3 octaves is really impressive without proper training. Is it?

None of my octaves is just screeching.

Comment: Three octaves is a great range. It will cover just about anything you are likely to sing. Make the most of it, and sing! Even if you do extend it, what would you do with it..?

Comment: Be prepared to watch this range lower with aging. I believe my range has lowered over the years, even after I graduated from university - I can now reach the A below the C below Middle C, but I'm losing my ability to hit notes above the C two octaves above Middle C.